# Celery class based task is ran synchronously instead of asynchronously

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have used `cookiecutter` to setup a django project. The relevant parts of the project should be:

File `config/settings/base.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ['foo.taskapp.celery.CeleryAppConfig']
if USE_TZ:
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
CELERY_BROKER_URL = env('CELERY_BROKER_URL', default='redis://redis:6379/0')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = CELERY_BROKER_URL
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 5 * 60
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60
### EDIT: I had forgotten these: ###
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True  # thats the problem
CELERY_TASK_EAGER_PROPAGATES = True
```

File `foo/taskapp/celery.py` (should be same as cookiecutter):

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.apps import apps, AppConfig
from django.conf import settings


if not settings.configured:
    # set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.local')  # pragma: no cover


app = Celery('foo')


class CeleryAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'foo.taskapp'
    verbose_name = 'Celery Config'

    def ready(self):
        # Using a string here means the worker will not have to
        # pickle the object when using Windows.
        # - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
        #   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
        app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
        installed_apps = [app_config.name for app_config in apps.get_app_configs()]
        app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: installed_apps, force=True)

        if hasattr(settings, 'RAVEN_CONFIG'):
            # Celery signal registration
            # Since raven is required in production only,
            # imports might (most surely will) be wiped out
            # during PyCharm code clean up started
            # in other environments.
            # @formatter:off
            from raven import Client as RavenClient
            from raven.contrib.celery import register_signal as raven_register_signal
            from raven.contrib.celery import register_logger_signal as raven_register_logger_signal
            # @formatter:on

            raven_client = RavenClient(dsn=settings.RAVEN_CONFIG['dsn'])
            raven_register_logger_signal(raven_client)
            raven_register_signal(raven_client)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')  # pragma: no cover
```

File `foo/foo/tasks.py`:

```
class TaskHandler(Task):
   name = "..."

   def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # this will block the main django thread
        time.sleep(10)

   def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        # enters here succesfully
        ...

   def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        # does NOT enter here if exception is raised in run()
        ...

tasktype = app.register_task(TaskHandler())
# app.tasks.register(TaskHandler())  # also tried this
```

File `foo/foo/views.py`:

```
class FooCreateView(FormValidMessageMixin, CreateView):
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user

        with transaction.atomic():

            # Save the self.object and render the success_url response page
            response = super().form_valid(form)

            ...

            kwargs = { ... }  # json serializable

            transaction.on_commit(lambda: tasktype.delay(**kwargs))
            # transaction.on_commit(lambda: TaskHandler().delay(**kwargs))  # also tried

        return response
```

The http response is returned to the browser only after the celery task is completed. There is no celery log produced neither in

`$ celery worker -A foo.taskapp -l info`

nor in the devserver (runserver) console. I can only see the django root logger's messages (no info either).

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure that CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER is not set to True in one of the config files, sometimes settings get messy when loading many other env files.

Comment: @marxin You guessed right! Stupid mistake of mine. I had forgotten that setting in `local.py` settings. Make your comment an answer if you want so that I can mark it as answer.